# How to make a typescript function that can be called, but can't be treated as value?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I've recently had a bug like this in my codebase:

```
const isMounted = useIsMounted();

//... later

if (isMounted) {
  // Some action
}
```

Except, oops! `isMounted` is a function with signature `() => boolean`, not a `boolean`. It should have been "`isMounted()`". A subtle bug.

Can you think of a way to prevent this kind of bug using typescript somehow?

Eg. declare that function is `never` for the purposes of querying its value, and yet still be able to call it?

Comment: I think what's more important (and not just for typescript) is to make it muscle memory to do strict and explicit comparisons instead of just checking truthyness because that in it of itself is a source of major source of headache e.g. do `if (isMounted === true)` or `if (isMounted !== null)` etc this may be a good habit to pick up

Comment: Disagree. In a dynamic javascript world, where there are many different kinds of falsy-ies (undefined, null, false, 0, ''), and which different libraries sometimes use interchangeably, this will IMO lead to more errors, not less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn on the `strictNullChecks` tsconfig option, and it will produce an error as expected:

[image]

> This condition will always return true since this function is always defined. Did you mean to call it instead?(2774)

Comment: It's not intuitive that the `strictNullChecks` option is the one to do this, but it's right nonetheless.

Comment: The reason `strictNullChecks` causes this is because without that option enabled, Typescript considers that the function itself could be `null`, so the value wouldn't always be truthy.

Comment: Damn, I explicitly disabled that so I wouldn't have to drag null-s around all over the place. Shame this comes in package with null checks.